# Unable to run flutter. Throws "couldn't find package fluttery:" error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiDxd.png)

```
description: A new Flutter project.


version: 0.9.91+50

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    SDK: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  audioplayers: ^0.11.0
  agora_rtc_engine: ^0.9.4
  cached_network_image: ^0.7.0
  country_pickers: ^1.0.1
  dio: ^2.0.22
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0
  flutter_rating: ^0.0.2
  fluttery: ^0.0.8
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.4.0
  get_it: ^1.0.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3
  image_picker: ^0.5.0+3
  intl: ^0.15.7
  intro_views_flutter: ^2.4.0
  permission_handler: ^3.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.2.1
  razorpay_plugin: ^0.2.9
  rxdart: ^0.21.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
  side_header_list_view: ^0.0.4
  strings: ^0.1.0
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  screen: ^0.0.5
  flutter_typeahead: ^1.4.0
  flutter_chips_input: ^1.2.0
  intro_slider: ^1.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  android: "ic_launcher"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/ic_launcher.jpg"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/images/
   - assets/
```

This is my pubspec.YAML file.
I have installed flutter and tried to run an existing flutter project on iPhone. 
When I try running flutter, I get this error.
I tried searching for solutions but couldn't find one. Can anyone let me know what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because flutter configured podfile that way. Default generated podfile by flutter won't allow ios build to download the nested dependencies.
To resolve you can alter podfile file by this and your issue would be resolved. 
Search for this piece of code

```
target 'Runner' do
  # Flutter Pod
```

And replace it with below

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  # Flutter Pod
```

**Update**

Fluttery package is removed/temporary down due to flutter upgrade. So you should update your pubspec.yaml file with

> fluttery_dart2: ^0.0.9

library to use the same functionality. Well this library will not be for long time once the original one will back.

**Please read the note [here](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttery_dart2#-readme-tab-)**

Comment: its quite clear error, if you search for fluttery on pub.dev you cannot find any package wihch named with yours;https://pub.dev/packages?q=fluttery

Comment: Where can I remove this fluttery dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find fluttery package in [pub](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=fluttery)

Maybe is deleted. Check `fluttery_dart2` as an alternative.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: he means that the library you're using is moved or deleted. You should better find an alternative of your fluttery library.